# Identify docx pptx xlsx and other msoffice files correctly rather than applicaton/zip

Tags: perl, upload, zip, ms-office, mime-types

Currently, im working on a perl script that should allow a file to be uploaded, and then process it, and then send it to a printer.

http://code.google.com/p/web-printer-http/

Apparently, both zip and microsoft office files ending in "...x" identify themselves as application/zip when using /usr/bin/file.

Any idea to differ them?

The differing should not be based on extension since the uploading system may be unabe to use extensions (like mobile phones and such).
Rather, it should judge the content entirely based on file content.

Comment: [file/libmagic](http://darwinsys.com/file/) **can** distinguish OASIS OpenDocument/"Libre Office" files from generic Zip files, so it is possible. Someone just needs to submit the appropriate signatures for Microsoft OOXML files to the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to distinguish between a .zip file and an Office Open XML file (like .docx, xslx, .pptx, etc) without peeking inside the zip.

All of the various open XML formats use .ZIP compression.  Therefore they *are* zip files.

If the zipfile conforms to the [Open Packaging Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions), then it may also be an Open XML (Office) document.

A good heuristic is if the zip file contains a file called `/[Content_Types].xml`, then it is an OPC file. To determine if the zip file contains a file of that name, you must read the zipfile directory.  Use a zip library to do that.